# Erro ao utilizar Hibernate para gerar tabelas e duvidas sobre

Tags: hibernate, java-ee, maven, jpa-2.0

Estou criando um webservice utilizando o Maven para gerenciar as dependências do meu projeto. No momento, estou querendo criar um banco de dados com base nos meus modelos.

Tenho quatro duvidas e um problema na minha tentativa:
1) Como faço para com o Java criar Foreign Key ?
2) Como faço para o Java criar o banco de dados ?
3) É possível criar apenas um arquivo .SQL ?
4)

O meu problema é este:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 2 exceptions. 
>   They are:
>   1. javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named persistence_unit_juntos
>   2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on br.com.felipejunges.juntos.controller.PessoaController
>
> org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:487)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Alguns dados do meu projeto:

*persistence.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
                                http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" 
             version="2.0" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

   <persistence-unit name="persistence_unit_juntos" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/juntosHibernate"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

*método que estou chamando no controller:*

```
@GET
    @Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    @Path("/lista")
    public List<Pessoa> ListarTudo(){

        List<Pessoa> pessoas =  new ArrayList<Pessoa>();

        List<Pessoa> listaEntityPessoas = repository.ListarTudo();

        for (Pessoa entity : listaEntityPessoas) {

            pessoas.add(new Pessoa(entity.getId(), entity.getNome(), entity.getSobrenome(), entity.getEmail(), 
                    entity.getSenha(), entity.getTelefone(), entity.getCep(), entity.getLogin(), 
                    entity.getRegistro(), entity.getGacesso_id(), entity.isBanAtivo(), 
                    entity.getLocalizacaoAtual()));
        }

        return pessoas;
    }
```

*Classe PessoaRepository:*

```
public class PessoaRepository {

    private final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public PessoaRepository(){

        /*CRIANDO O NOSSO EntityManagerFactory COM AS PORPRIEDADOS DO ARQUIVO persistence.xml */
        this.entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence_unit_juntos");

        this.entityManager = this.entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    /**
     * CRIA UM NOVO REGISTRO NO BANCO DE DADOS
     * */
    public void Salvar(Pessoa pessoaEntity){

        this.entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        this.entityManager.persist(pessoaEntity);
        this.entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    /**
     * ALTERA UM REGISTRO CADASTRADO
     * */
    public void Alterar(Pessoa pessoaEntity){

        this.entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        this.entityManager.merge(pessoaEntity);
        this.entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    /**
     * RETORNA TODAS AS PESSOAS CADASTRADAS NO BANCO DE DADOS 
     * */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Pessoa> ListarTudo(){

        return this.entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Pessoa p ORDER BY p.nome").getResultList();
    }

    /**
     * CONSULTA UMA PESSOA CADASTRA PELO CÓDIGO
     * */
    public Pessoa GetPessoa(Integer id){

        return this.entityManager.find(Pessoa.class, id);
    }

    /**
     * EXCLUINDO UM REGISTRO PELO CÓDIGO
    **/
    public void Excluir(Integer id){

        Pessoa pessoa = this.GetPessoa(id);

        this.entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        this.entityManager.remove(pessoa);
        this.entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

    }

    public Pessoa Login(String email){

        return (Pessoa) this.entityManager
                .createQuery("SELECT p FROM Pessoa p WHERE p.email  = :pemail")
                .setParameter("pemail", email).getSingleResult();
    }

    public boolean HabilitarConta(Pessoa pessoa){
        return false;
    }

}
```

E este é o meu Modelo/Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="pessoa")
public class Pessoa {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="nome")
    private String nome;

    @Column(name="sobrenome")
    private String sobrenome;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="senha")
    private String senha;

    @Column(name="telefone")
    private String telefone;

    @Column(name="cep")
    private Cep cep;

    @Column(name="login")
    private Timestamp login;

    @Column(name="registro")
    private Timestamp registro;

    @Column(name="gacesso_id")
    private Permissao gacesso_id;

    @Column(name="banAtivo")
    private boolean banAtivo;

    @Column(name="localizacaoAtual")
    private Localizacao localizacaoAtual;

    public Pessoa() {

    }

    public Pessoa(int id, String nome, String sobrenome, String email, String senha, 
            String telefone, Cep cep, Timestamp login, Timestamp registro, 
            Permissao gacesso_id, boolean banAtivo, Localizacao localizacaoAtual) {

        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
        this.email = email;
        this.senha = senha;
        this.telefone = telefone;
        this.cep = cep;
        this.login = login;
        this.registro = registro;
        this.gacesso_id = gacesso_id;
        this.banAtivo = banAtivo;
        this.localizacaoAtual = localizacaoAtual;


    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getSobrenome() {
        return sobrenome;
    }
    public void setSobrenome(String sobrenome) {
        this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
    }
    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }
    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }
    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }
    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }
    public Cep getCep() {
        return cep;
    }
    public void setCep(Cep cep) {
        this.cep = cep;
    }
    public Timestamp getLogin() {
        return login;
    }
    public void setLogin(Timestamp login) {
        this.login = login;
    }
    public Timestamp getRegistro() {
        return registro;
    }
    public void setRegistro(Timestamp registro) {
        this.registro = registro;
    }
    public Permissao getGacesso_id() {
        return gacesso_id;
    }
    public void setGacesso_id(Permissao gacesso_id) {
        this.gacesso_id = gacesso_id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Localizacao getLocalizacaoAtual() {
        return localizacaoAtual;
    }

    public void setLocalizacaoAtual(Localizacao localizacaoAtual) {
        this.localizacaoAtual = localizacaoAtual;
    }

    public boolean isBanAtivo() {
        return banAtivo;
    }

    public void setBanAtivo(boolean banAtivo) {
        this.banAtivo = banAtivo;
    }
}
```

Testei com o /cadastrar (Salvar no Repositório) e não funcionou. 
No caso, tenho outro projeto de Webservice que segui um tutorial e adaptei para minha solução para apresentação na aula, agora estou querendo criar para meu TCC.
O não tinha no outro projeto:
a) Criação automática do banco, ou seja, criei o .sql na mão;
b) Referências de outros modelos em um modelo.

Editado:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message A MultiException has 2 exceptions. They are:

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: persistence_unit_juntos] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on br.com.felipejunges.juntos.controller.PessoaController

    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:487)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: persistence_unit_juntos] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on br.com.felipejunges.juntos.controller.PessoaController

    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:391)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:162)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:767)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:706)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:172)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:284)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:318)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: persistence_unit_juntos] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954)
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:884)
    org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    br.com.felipejunges.juntos.repository.PessoaRepository.<init>(PessoaRepository.java:20)
    br.com.felipejunges.juntos.controller.PessoaController.<init>(PessoaController.java:21)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1350)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:271)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:365)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:162)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:767)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:706)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:172)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:284)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:318)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: br.com.felipejunges.juntos.entity.Pessoa, at table: ban, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(admin_id)]
    org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:411)
    org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:384)
    org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226)
    org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:529)
    org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265)
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329)
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:464)
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:881)
    org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    br.com.felipejunges.juntos.repository.PessoaRepository.<init>(PessoaRepository.java:20)
    br.com.felipejunges.juntos.controller.PessoaController.<init>(PessoaController.java:21)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1350)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:271)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:365)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:162)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:767)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:706)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:172)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:284)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:318)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O primeiro erro (No Persistence provider for EntityManager) normalmente é porque o hibernate não encontrou o arquivo persistence.xml. Ele costuma ficar em /src/META-INF.

Em relação à criação automática do seu banco de dados, a propriedade "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", que já está no seu persistence.xml, é responsável por isso. Os valores possíveis são:

- validate: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
- update: update the schema.
- create: creates the schema, destroying previous data.
- create-drop: drop the schema when the SessionFactory is closed explicitly, typically when the application is stopped.

Por último, sobre a criação de FK: ela é criada automaticamente pelo hibernate, de acordo com as annotations de relacionamento (@ManyToMany, @ManyToOne, @OneToMany).

Sugiro iniciar pela resolução do primeiro problema, que é fazer com que o hibernate encontre o seu arquivo persistence.xml.

Comment: Corrigi o erro de localização e algumas dependências, e agora foi me apresentando: [PersistenceUnit: persistence_unit_juntos] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory, isto teria haver com COLUMN referenciando para outros objetos ?

Comment: Poderia postar o stack trace completo da exceção? Esse parece ser um erro mais geral e, normalmente, a causa raiz é mostrada no fim do stack trace.

Comment: Coloquei o log do novo erro a publicação

Comment: A causa raiz é "org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: br.com.felipejunges.juntos.entity.Pessoa, at table: ban, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(admin_id)]". O Hibernate não conseguiu identificar o tipo para uma coluna chamada "admin_id". Não encontrei no seu post original. Poderia enviar?

Comment: Então acho que sei o erro, são as foreign key, que não mencionei nos modelos corretamente no momento! Estarei deixando a resposta concluída, porque a duvida inicial, você já respondeu! Obrigado!